# Log Problem and bash script

Tags: debian, logging, debian-lenny

I have 11 Debian servers running on rackspace cloud hosting. All running VHCS2 for hosting management. 1 server is used for application and 10 are used for only smtp. My question is regarding smtp servers. Each server hosted 1 domain. My problem is when my client use smtp 
there's a log created in this directory

```
/var/log/
```

but within 24 hours drives are full and server refuse all smtp connections. Then I deleted the logs and ran following command to check the disk space.

```
df -h
```

but it shows hdd still full and server is still refusing the smtp connections. Then I ran following command to see the truth

```
du --max-depth=1 -h
```

It shows the truth. The real disk space used. Then I rebooted the server and now server working fine. But after few hours same situation happened. Then I created the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -fr /var/log/*
rm -fr /var/log/apache2/*.log
rm -fr /var/log/apache2/*.log.*
rm -fr /var/log/apache2/users/*
rm -fr /var/log/apache2/backup/*

reboot
```

It worked for days but after that logs are again filling the hdd.

Now I want the following solutions. If anybody can help me.

1. When I delete files from server hdd will free up without rebooting
2. Log should be in specific range. Like a specific size of file where old data overwrite with new data

Answer (score 7):

1. Deleting the log files alone won't help. You need to tell the daemon to close the log file, usually by sending it a SIGHUP.
2. `logrotate` should be handling the logs, and it can use various criteria to determine when the log should be rotated.
3. Your logs are filling up *awful* fast. Either figure out what's flooding your logs, send your logs to another machine for handling and storage, or mount a separate volume at /var/log so that it will be the only volume affected.

Answer (score 4):

You really need to work out which log(s) are filling the disk. 
Once you know which logs are the problem take a look at them and see why they are growing so quickly.

Is there too much information being logged ? Reduce the logging level of the application. 
Are lots of errors being logged ? Investigate and fix.
...

Once you have control of the logs you can then use `logrotate` to help manage them.